# How can I fix a Virtual Multiblog install that has no errors, but won't show all my sites?

Tags: multisite, virtual-hosts

I've been using [Stephen Rider's Virtual Multiblog](http://striderweb.com/nerdaphernalia/features/virtual-multiblog/) system for WordPress for a while now, and recently, I decided to add one more blog to my existing batch of three. The difference was, while all my other blogs existed as subdomains, this time I wanted WordPress for my main domain.

Somehow, this broke all my other (non-WP) sites, because they started to look in my WordPress directory for the folders containing the other sites.

At present, I have one site that's a virtual user/symlink site that is working.
The other two sites, including the one for the subdomain in which WordPress is actually installed with the Virtual Multiblog system, aren't loading at all. They try and take me to the install script (which I've removed access to until I can resolve this issue).

I've made sure that the mb-config-VUSER.php files are set up properly, and compared the working site's config files to the non-working ones, but I can't think of anything.

I'm guessing this is something on my host's end, but they're insisting the symlinks are set up correctly, and there's some redirect somewhere that's breaking everything.

Anyone have any ideas, or any suggestions for possibly switching my existing sites/database tables from VMB to WP's own Multisite feature if I can't get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help you, but I would need more info, such as your $vusers list and the names of the blogs (you can use example.com for the domain).

Show me what you had that worked, and what you have now that doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Welcome. Requests for clarification should probably be posted as comments to the question, not as answers. StackExchange doesn't work like a discussion forum, which puzzled me at first. I would repost this as a comment to the question and wait until you have a reasonably viable solution before posting an answer.

Comment: How?  This blank appears to be for comments on my "answer", but I don't see how to comment on the original question.

Comment: There is an "add comment" just below the question. Look just above the ugly orange-pink "start a bounty" link. Hmmm... but it looks like [you need 50 rep to see it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). That throws a wrench in things. You should have that in no time. I looked at your blog. :)